Evitar que el usuario ingrese a la página si no ha logeado
Quiero evitar que mi usuario ingrese a mi página si no ha logeado. Ya lo hice con $_SESSION, pero no sé por qué no funciona.
Aquí el código (estatus.php), lo que ocurre es que me regresa a acceso_estatus.php aún si la condición no se cumple.
    <?php 
    session_start();

    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuarios = "root";
    $clave = "";
    $db = "datos";

    $enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuarios, $clave, $db);
    $enlace->set_charset("utf8");

// Aqui quiero validar username, si la condición es correcta no hace nada, pero sino, quiero que me regrese al login (acceso_estatus.php)

       if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
         header("Location: acceso_estatus.php");
       }
 ?>

Aqui el código de acceso_estatus.
  <?php
  $enlace = new mysqli("localhost","root","","datos");
  $enlace->set_charset("utf8");

  session_start();

        if(isset($_POST['Ingresar'])){
           if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['contraseña'])) {
              echo "Campos sin llenar";
          } else {
              $username = $_POST['username'];
              $contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
 
               $valor = $enlace->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username=? AND 
                                         contraseña=?");
               $valor->bind_param("ss", $username, $contraseña);
               $valor->execute();
               $resultados = $valor->get_result();

                   if ($resultados->num_rows == 1) {

// Hasta donde tengo entendido se tiene que validar desde el login en $_SESSION para saber que ya logeo, despues me redirige a estatus.

                       $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //autentifico la varibale según yo.

                       header("Location: estatus.php");
                       exit();
                  } else {
                     echo "acceso denegado";
                  }
         }
    }
?>


Al no poder replicar tu escenario no se si solo es el session_start() lo que tienes mal, pues eso debe ir antes que cualquier código.
Pero por si las dudas acá te va un ejemplo sencillo
index.php
// Esto siempre en primera línea
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    // Si no hay una sesión que me redirecciones al login
    header("Location: login.php");
}

// Si hay sesión me dirá "Hola + Nombre de Usuario"
echo "Hola ".$_SESSION['user'];

login.php
<?php
    // Esto siempre en primera línea
    session_start();
    if ($_POST) {
        /* Si hay un POST (del formulario) que me llene
           mis variables de Sesión */
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        // Redirecciono
        header("Location: index.php");

        // Probar el formulario siempre es bueno
        // echo "<pre>";
        //  print_r($_POST);
        // echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Formulario básico -->
    <form action="" method="POST">
        Nombre
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nombre" required="">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Resultado en pantalla: Hola OCHOA
